Who is the stranger?
Deuteronomy 29: 22:- So that the generation to come of your children that shall rise up after you, and the stranger that shall come from a far land, shall say, when they see the plagues of that land, and the sicknesses which the Lord hath laid upon it;...

The "stranger" is simply any foreigner or alien, ie, visiting non-Israelite.  Most versions translate the text using the word "foreigner" or similar.  See https://biblehub.com/deuteronomy/29-22.htm

A “stranger” is simply a foreigner or someone who comes from a distant land.
Gill's Exposition of the Entire Bible:

and the stranger that shall come from a far land; on trade and
business, or for the sake of travelling, his road either lying through
it, or his curiosity leading him to see it:

Take note of the word in the Hebrew:

From nokri:

Original Word: נָכְרִי
Definition: foreign, alien

So, the heart of the verse is saying that: strangers, those who are not part of the Israelite community, will also bear witness to the plagues and sicknesses that God will bring upon the land as a result of the people’s disobedience.
